# Find x in infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> We have: $$ x^{x^{x^{ x^{x ^{x ^{\dots}}}}}} =
>  2.$$

I tried a reasoning by recursion:

For $n=1$:
\begin{align} 
x^x &= 2 \\
\implies x\ln x &= \ln 2
\end{align}

For $n=2$:
\begin{align} 
x^{x^x} &= 2 \\
\implies x\ln x^x &= \ln 2  \\
\implies x^2\ln x  &= \ln 2 \\
\end{align}

For an arbitrary $n$ we can solve:
$$x^n \ln x = \ln 2 $$

But for $n \to \infty$, I can't seem to find something.
Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1017322.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If the solution exists then

$$x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}=x^{(x^{x^{\cdots}})}=x^{(2)}=x^2=2.$$

The stuff in the power is equal to $2$ hence we can replace it by $2$.